# Randomly pick array values, add them up, until you get a certain value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array with undefined number of elements

```
 $marks=array('2','4','9','3');
 target=50;
```

I want to randomly loop through the array, add up the values I fetch until the total is my target.

```
 $total=0;        /////initialize total
 for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($marks);++$i)
         {
       /////////Pick up random values add them up until $total==$target
       /////////return the new array with selected elements that sums up to 
       /////////target
         }
```

I hope my question is clear, also note that the loop should not iterate too many times since the elements might never add up to the total. I have tried adding the items in line but to no avail. Thanks in advance

Comment: what if the sum exceeds the target?

Comment: I encountered them same issue. It should not exceed. If it does, we would rather randomize the loop . @Dagon

Comment: you get to 49, there is no 1 to pick, what do you do ?

Comment: My code got stuck at 49.

Comment: Ok just add more elements in the array, they are dynamic and of unknown length @HassanAlthaf

Comment: @jonah Yes, it will work. Look at the `$index` variable, I have made it to work with any number of elements in the array.

Comment: Plus, I have built some other logic so that it does what is expected. Please read what I have written.

Comment: @jonah I made a tiny change in the code of mine. Please make sure you check that out.

Comment: @Hassan, I got your code to work, but kindly, i want the code to return a new array with the selected elements that adds up to 50. Sorry, arrays confuse me a little

Comment: Thanks. works my case. let me review other answers @HassanAlthaf

Comment: @jonah Please select the right answer.

Comment: All answers are working fine. am trying the best for my solution and then select the right answer. @HassanAlthaf .

Comment: Select the most efficient one which does the job __perfectly__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this'll work for you and always return you value of count to be `50` only

```
$marks = array(6,7,9,6,7,9,3,4,12,23,4,6,4,5,7,8,4);
$target = 50;

function sum($marks, $target) {
    $count = 0;
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++) {
        if ($count < $target) {
            $add = $marks[array_rand($marks)];
            $count = $count + $add;
            $result['add'][] = $add;
        } elseif ($count == $target) {
            break;
        } elseif ($count >= $target) {
            $extra = $count - $target;
            $count = $count-$extra;
            $result['extra'] = $extra;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(sum($marks, $target));
```

Comment: If you need any change then let me know I'll make that relative changes

Comment: Bug detected, look at this: `4 6 9 13 22 26 30 32 41 44 47 51 50`

Comment: It's just cutting off the extra part.. :L

Comment: I'm not sure about what OP wants over here

Comment: @NarendraSisodia. You code is getting my target. One last thing, instead of returning $count, please return a new array with the used elements that made up the sum. And no element should be repeated. I have tried, but ended up breaking your code. Thanks

Comment: Please use the following  array $marks(6,7,9,6,7,9,3,4,12,23,4,6,4,5,7,8,4); so that we see the bug pointed by @hassan. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer and its resulting the multidimensional array `add` those values i.e. used from `$marks` array and `extra` i.e. used to remove the extra value @jonah

Comment: I dont have an idea what 'extra' is. But the code is doing the job. I just need to try out something more. Thanks alot @Narendra

Comment: That `extra = $count - $target;`

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your logic, a `while` loop might make more sense:

```
<?php
$marks = array(2, 4, 9, 3);
$target = 50;
$sum = 0;
$i = 0; // to keep track of which iteration we're on

// PHP can natively randomize an array:
shuffle($marks);

while ($sum < $target && $i < count($marks)) {
    $sum += $marks[$i];
    $i++; // keep track of which iteration we're on
}

// after the loop, we've either added every number in $marks,
// or $sum >= $target
```

Don't forget that it might exceed `$target` without ever being equal to it, as Dagon pointed out in a comment.

Look into PHP's native array shuffle: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Your solutions looks like what I need. But how do I return the array of the items that are selected. @Jeff

Comment: Since the shuffling occurs before the numbers are added, check if `$target` has been reached, and if so, the desired sequence is `$marks[0...$i]`. [array_slice()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) might be helpful :) I can explain more if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used a lower target of 15 so that array can loop maybe through the first three elements. But echoing $sum gives 18 and 16. Let me check array slice and see..

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good alternative for the above answer.

Why I say so is that I have set it in such a way that it doesn't let the total go over the target, and when there is such a situation, the current number in the array is decremented by one and added as a new element so that if there is no possible number in the stack, there will be one eventually making this loop not go on infinitely. :)

```
<?php

$marks = ['2', '4', '9', '3'];
$target = 50;

$total = 0;

$numbersUsed = [];

while($total != $target) {
    $index = rand(0, count($marks) - 1);
    $number = $marks[$index];

    if($number + $total > $target) {
        $number = 0;
        $marks[] = $marks[$index] - 1;
    } else {
        $numbersUsed[] = $number;
    }

    $total += $number;

    echo $total . "\n";
}

// To see which numbers were used:
print_r($numbersUsed);
?>
```

**Testing:**

Starting with the array `['2', '4', '9', '3']`,

We loop and get the result:

`4 13 17 20 22 31 35 44 46 48 48 48 48 50`

And we get this array which includes the numbers used to get the final result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 2
)
```

Comment: @jonah I modified my code a bit, please make sure you change to that code.